# How to define maximum generated tests per data type using Arbitrary or other type class?

Tags: haskell

## Background

Assuming the subject to test is the module *Huge*, and we are using the Test.Framework with Test.QuickCheck (, and Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2).

```
module Huge
    (
        ...
    ) where

data TooHugeToTestAll = ToHuge { ra :: Int, rb :: Int, rc :: Int, rd :: Int }
    deriving (Show)

hugeProduct :: TooHugeToTestAll -> Integer
...

isAnyZeroOrNegative :: TooHugeToTestAll -> Bool
...

shiftLHuge :: TooHugeToTestAll -> TooHugeToTestAll
shiftLHuge (ToHuge a b c d) = (ToHuge b c d a)
```

...and assuming the test is performed by `stack test`, and compiling *Spec.hs* to test the module *Huge*.

```
-- Spec.hs

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fno-warn-orphans #-}

import qualified Test.Framework as TF
import qualified Test.Framework.Providers.HUnit as FHU
import qualified Test.Framework.Providers.QuickCheck2 as QC2 -- supports Test.QuickCheck with 'testProperty'
import qualified Test.HUnit as HU
import qualified Test.QuickCheck as QC

import qualified Huge as H

main :: IO ()
main = 
    TF.defaultMainWithOpts
        [
            FHU.testCase "Law #1 test case #1" ((H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 2 3 5 7)) HU.@?= 210), 
            FHU.testCase "Law #2 test case #1" ((H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 0 3 5 7)) HU.@?= 0), 
            FHU.testCase "Law #2 test case #2" ((H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 2 0 5 7)) HU.@?= 0), 
            FHU.testCase "Law #2 test case #3" ((H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 2 3 0 7)) HU.@?= 0), 
            FHU.testCase "Law #2 test case #4" ((H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 2 3 5 0)) HU.@?= 0), 
            (QC2.testProperty
                    "Law #1" 
                    (\huge -> 
                        (
                            (not (H.isAnyZeroOrNegative huge)) 
                            QC.==> 
                            ((H.hugeProduct huge) == ((fromIntegral (H.ra huge)) * (fromIntegral (H.rb huge)) * (fromIntegral (H.rc huge)) * (fromIntegral (H.rd huge)))) ) ) ), 
            QC2.testProperty
                "Law #2" 
                (\huge -> 
                    ( 
                        (H.isAnyZeroOrNegative huge) 
                        QC.==> 
                        ((H.hugeProduct huge) == 0) ) ), 
            QC2.testProperty
                "Law #3" 
                (\nj -> 
                    ( 
                        ((H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 2 3 5 nj)) /= 0) 
                        QC.==> 
                        (((H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 2 3 5 1)) * (fromIntegral nj)) == (H.hugeProduct (H.ToHuge 2 3 5 nj))) ) )
        ]
        mempty

instance QC.Arbitrary H.TooHugeToTestAll where
    arbitrary = 
        do
            a <- QC.frequency
                [
                    (1000, QC.choose (-2, 4)),  -- around 0
                    (1, QC.choose (3, 10000))   -- up to 10000
                ]
            b <- QC.frequency
                [
                    (1000, QC.choose (-2, 4)),  -- around 0
                    (1, QC.choose (3, 10000))   -- up to 10000
                ]
            c <- QC.frequency
                [
                    (1000, QC.choose (-2, 4)),  -- around 0
                    (1, QC.choose (3, 10000))   -- up to 10000
                ]
            d <- QC.frequency
                [
                    (1000, QC.choose (-2, 4)),  -- around 0
                    (1, QC.choose (3, 10000))   -- up to 10000
                ]
            return (H.ToHuge a b c d)
```

As we see above, we can control the random distribution of an instance of type class `Arbitrary`.

## Question

As far as I understand we cannot control the maximum generated tests)<sup>1</sup> in the same manner (by creating an instance for the data type *TooHugeToTestAll*), can we? If yes, how?

I already agonized my brain about Testable, but I do not understand the design of `Test.Framework`, and `Test.QuickCheck`.

---

)<sup>1</sup> Maximum generated tests is meaning in terms of `TestOptions`.

Comment: You can use [`withMaxSuccess`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:withMaxSuccess) to specify the number of tests to run.

Comment: As an aside, your `arbitrary` implementation could be quite a bit simpler: `arbitrary = ToHuge <$> f <*> f <*> f <*> f where f = frequency [...]`